# Specify keys for pydantic nested model

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a structure similar to this in JSON

```
{
  'name': 'My Company',
  'region': {
    'us': {
      'person': {
        'name': 'John'
      }
    },
    'mx': {
      'person': {
        'name': 'Juan'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to model it as pydantic classes

```
class Person(BaseModel):
  name: str

class Region(BaseModel):
  person: Person
```

but I'm having trouble modelling the `Company` class because I want to limit the keywords that can be used, I tried something like this:

```
REGIONS = Literal['us', 'mx']

class Company(BaseModel):
  name: str
  region: Dict[REGIONS, Region]
```

but that doesn't work, it also introduces issues when I have a function where I need to get those inner values, eg:

```
# This method is part of Company - it doesn't work
def lower_case_person(cls):
  return cls.region.person.name
```

How can I model this to constrain the keywords for `Region` while at the same time maintain it's behaviour as an object rather than a dictionary?

Edit:

In an actual scenario, an example of the JSON will come as:

```
{
  'name': 'My Company',
  'region': {
    'mx': {
      'person': {
        'name': 'Juan'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How many regions do you anticipate? Only these two? (Yes it is relevant for filtering out viable answers.)

Comment: Also: `lower_case_person` as a classmethod does not make sense because only an **instance** of `Company` will actually have the field `region` (and so on). I assume you meant to write it as a normal instance method. And if `region` is actually an object (in the JSON data), that can have the keys `us` or `mx`, how on earth is `self.region.person` supposed to resolve? `region` may have **two** key-value-pairs, where each object has its own `person` key. You need to edit your question and provide valid input data and your desired output.

Comment: So on runtime I will have the JSON with the proper region code there instead of multiple, the example is just to give more context.

Comment: The example is confusing because it 1) is invalid JSON and 2) does not represent the data schema you _actually_ seem to expect. Please edit your question and include an **actual** [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means one complete piece of code that we can copy, paste and execute to see your problem and include your desired output.

Comment: There, provided an example.

Comment: Well, I tried. I even linked the article explaining what an MRE is. Good luck.

Comment: Well, thank you very much nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this with a `validator` (https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/)

```py
from pydantic import validator 

class Company(BaseModel):
    name: str
    region: Dict[str, Region]

    @validator('region')
    def just_us_or_mx(cls, v):
        for k in v:
            if not (k in ['us', 'mx']):
                raise ValueError("Keys must be 'us' or 'mx'")
        return v
```